How can I write a JavaScript variable inside double quotation marks in a template literal?
I have this code:
        const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.innerHTML = `
            <button class='btn btn-download'>
                <span class='icon'>&#8681;</span>
                Download Subtitle
            </button>
            <span>as</span>
            <select id=`outputFormatSelectId`>
                <option value="text">Text</option>
                <option value="text-with-time">Text with Time</option>
                <option value="json">JSON</option>
                <option value="srt">SRT</option>
            </select>`;

Notice <select id="outputFormatSelectId"> has a id outputFormatSelectId. Actually this id is a variable which has a value. But I don't understand how can put this variable inside **id=  **
Though it's not the full code, but just the related code. If something is unclear please ask me for clarification.
Actually my confusion is about Template literal. While the code block is inside a template literal, then how can i use another variable in this template literal?

The documentation shows how to use variables in template literals.  Specifically look at the ${} syntax used.  For example: <select id="${outputFormatSelectId}">

@David Yes I think that's a good insight.

This question is similar to: ES6 JavaScript template literals - What they can and can't do. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As @David said in comment, you need to something like this:
<select id="${outputFormatSelectId}">

So your corrected code will be:
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = `
<button class='btn btn-download'>
    <span class='icon'>&#8681;</span>
    Download Subtitle
</button>
<span>as</span>
<select id="${outputFormatSelectId}">
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="text-with-time">Text with Time</option>
    <option value="json">JSON</option>
    <option value="srt">SRT</option>
</select>`;


did you mean this?
    const outputFormatSelectId = "this-is-id";
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = `
        <button class='btn btn-download'>
            <span class='icon'>&#8681;</span>
            Download Subtitle
        </button>
        <span>as</span>
        <select id='${outputFormatSelectId}'>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="text-with-time">Text with Time</option>
            <option value="json">JSON</option>
            <option value="srt">SRT</option>
        </select>`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

By using ${outputFormatSelectId} within the template literal, you would tell to JavaScript to evaluate the expression inside ${} and insert its value into the string.
This way, if outputFormatSelectId is a variable holding a string value (like "mySelectId"), it will be inserted as the id attribute's value.
